Is it safe to charge a 4v lead battery with 5v charger and a diode?
I have bought this Chinese SMD charger light that comes with 5v usb charging port.
I have just opened it to see how it charges with a 5v charger. After opening it I have been very surprised to see that they just put a diode (only) between the battery and 5v input. Nothing else.

How safe is it to charge the battery like that?

Is it even good for the batteries health.

Is it safe for my phone charger to charge this device with my phone's charger.


I measured the 4v battery reaches to 5v+ while its charging.

Is it safe for 4v lead acid battery to reach 5v?




It's safe if you are convinced the product is from a reputable supplier who provides believable quality assurance and decent guidelines on how to use the device. This usually rules out a lot of far east manufactured equipment and products. Personally, I wouldn't touch it with a barge pole based on what info you have provided.


It is not dangerous like it will immediately explode. But it will degrade the batteries with higher than normal 2.5V per cell float voltage.

No, not good for battery health to float them at higher than normal charge voltage

Your USB supply (it's not a charger) likely tolerates a bit of abuse, but it's not intended to drive lead-acid batteries through diode. There may be overcurrent and undervoltage at the supply, when batteries are empty.

Safe and not good are two different things. Overcharging lead acid cells means the electrolyte may vent hydrogen gas that may explode, and the electrolyte may boil and dry up. It will only be potentially unsafe if the hydrogen explodes.



A lead-acid battery should have no more that 2.30 to 2.35V per cell applied continuously (here's a good discussion on Pb-acid charging).
(Where did you find a 4V lead-acid battery?)

A 4V battery that was found inside a bought device must consist of two cells.
